# MySQL запрос из двух таблиц с условием

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Приветствую, собственно вопрос, как реализовать запрос на выборку из двух таблиц с таким условием:

Есть таблица

customers `{id, name, address}`

```
1 Вася Адрес1
2 Петя Адрес2
```

И таблица

```
comments {id, cust_id, comment, date}

1 1 Молодец Дата
2 2 Хороший Дата
3 1 Норм    Дата
4 2 Сойдет  Дата
5 1 Ок      Дата
```

**И необходимо выбрать всех покупателей плюс к каждому покупателю последний комментарий. Вот так надо**

```
1 Вася Ок
2 Петя Сойдет
```

Пробовал пойти таким путем

```
SELECT U.*, S.comment
FROM customers AS U 
LEFT JOIN comments AS S 
  ON S.cust_id = U.id 
AND (
SELECT max(S2.id) 
  FROM comments AS S2
) GROUP BY U.id ORDER BY S.comment DESC
```

В результате имею строки с первыми комментариями...

```
1 Вася Молодец
2 Петя Хороший
```

Прошу помочь советом/примером, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, решение данной задачи может выглядеть следующим образом.

```
SELECT customers.id, customers.name, comments.comment
FROM customers
  JOIN comments
    ON comments.cust_id = customers.id
WHERE comments.id = (
  SELECT max(comments.id)
  FROM comments
  WHERE comments.cust_id = customers.id
)
```

Comment: Да уж, знание - сила. Спасибо Alexey Novopashin и VadimTagil